# Equivant of git's --color-words or --word-diff in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Let's say I had this file with these contents:

```
One two three
```

And let's say I modified this file to look like this:

```
One TWO three
```

A typical diff output would be:

```
- One two three
+ One TWO three
```

However, Git offers options like `--color-words` or `--word-diff=color` to show this difference in one line, colouring the word deleted in red and colourig the word added in green:

[image: diff in one line showing: One twoTWO three]

Does Mercurial have an option like this? Something like `hg diff --color-words`?

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for but I like to use https://github.com/mookid/diffr (just pipe the `hg d` output to it)